# Redirect old link with Symbol to new URL using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Hi I have found so many not found errors on webmaster tools so I tried to redirect them like this

```
Redirect 301 /cars/2004@$Toyota@$Alessandro%20Volta%20Conceptg.html http://www.example.net/blog/
```

But I see all my redirect is woking but all link that have symbols like @ % $ is not working, can anyone please help me what rules I need to use for this kind of link?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /cars/2004@\$Toyota@\$Alessandro%20Volta%20Conceptg.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.net/blog/ [R,L]
```

Comment: Hi thank you, but this giving 500 internal server error.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to escape the $ char in uri, It's fixed now.